# How to compare an element in the list with increment of same incremented element should be greater than 12 hrs?

Tags: java

I have a list like below am comparing 1st element to 2nd and 2nd to 3rd and soon till 12 and should do click on element if it is greater than 12hrs

Here list may change and have any number of values every time it will not be 12 it may increase or decrease.

```
etcList: [28 04:15, 28 17:45, 29 00:45, 29 08:45, 29 19:35, 30 03:25, 30 12:00, 30 18:50, 31 11:20, 31 21:30, 01 06:15, 01 15:45]
```

```
for (int i = 1; i < etcList.size(); i++) {
            if (getDifference(etcList.get(i), etcList.get(i + 1)) > 12) {
                etcList.get(i + 1).$x("preceding::tr[1]/td[7]/span/span").click();
                CREW_CHANGE.shouldBe(visible).selectOption(Constants.CREW_CHANGE_POINT);
            }
}
```

But am getting this error:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 12, Size: 12
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
```

Comment: Try looping to the second to last element.

Comment: Try to compare elements `i - 1` and `i` (instead of `i` and `i + 1`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this

```
for (int i = 1; i < etcList.size(); i++)
```

to

```
for (int i = 1; i < etcList.size() - 1; i++)
```

this prevents the program from going beyond the array's size at this point -
`etcList.get(i + 1)`
because for an array of size 12, your `i` would go upto 11. but the range of index for the array is also from 0 to 11 which means that, in the mentioned step your program will check for element at index 12 due to `(i+1)` and `i` being 11 in the last step which does not exist.